# How to count the delay of loading a url and restart loading next URL in row using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a list of 50 URL links in Excel column. I extract my data but there is a case that a URL do a timeout, I think because the webpage has high definition photos. This is the one of the links

https://www.wavemotion.gr/el/shop/smartphone-accessories/itap-magnetic-air-vent-car-mount

How can I go to next URL if the delay of loading is above 10 seconds? I have the following so far

```
'Set Worksheet
Set wks = wb.Sheets("wavemotion")
'Limit rows
lastrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'Set IE display
ie.Visible = True


For i = 2 To lastrow

mylink = wks.Cells(i, 2).Value

ie.Navigate mylink

Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5


While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
t = Timer
Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next
'change row color           
    wks.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 38

    Set product_sku = ie.Document.querySelector(".single-product__sku")
    wks.Cells(i, "A").Value = product_sku.innerText

    Set price = ie.Document.querySelector(".price .woocommerce-Price-amount")
    wks.Cells(i, "E").Value = price.innerText

    Set availability = ie.Document.querySelector(".stock.in-stock ")
    Set availability = ie.Document.querySelector(".stock.out-of-stock ")
    Set availability = ie.Document.querySelector(".stock.out-of-stock ")

    wks.Cells(i, "D").Value = availability.innerText

    Set product_name = ie.Document.querySelector(".single-product__title")
    wks.Cells(i, "C").Value = product_name.innerText

    'Set product_color = ie.Document.querySelector(".single-product__colors__label ")
    'wks.Cells(i, "G").Value = product_color.innerText


    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop
If price Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

wks.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 0

Next i

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would extend the Const as that is where the wait time is supposed to be determined. Then re-organise your code so you can exit earlier if you are able to set your target element. Have a test for Is Nothing on Set element and only execute next lines (related to that url) if Not Is Nothing.

I am a little uncomfortable about the structure of navigate within the loop and would like to test if you have any urls you know hang. As I have now added setting the element and navigating into the same block you might want to add another second or two to the Const.

```
Option Explicit   
Public Sub test()
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    'other code
    Set wks = wb.Sheets("wavemotion")
    LastRow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ie.Visible = True

    For i = 2 To LastRow

        mylink = wks.Cells(i, 2).Value        
        t = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents          
            ie.Navigate2 mylink

            While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            On Error Resume Next
            Set availability = ie.document.querySelector(".stock.in-stock ")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While availability Is Nothing

        If Not availability Is Nothing Then

            wks.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
            Set product_sku = ie.document.querySelector(".single-product__sku")
            wks.Cells(i, "A").Value = product_sku.innerText
            Set price = ie.document.querySelector(".price .woocommerce-Price-amount")
            wks.Cells(i, "E").Value = price.innerText
            wks.Cells(i, "D").Value = availability.innerText
            Set product_name = ie.document.querySelector(".single-product__title")
            wks.Cells(i, "C").Value = product_name.innerText
            Set product_color = ie.document.querySelector(".single-product__colors__label ")
            wks.Cells(i, "G").Value = product_color.innerText
            wks.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            Set price = Nothing: Set availability = Nothing '.... etc
        End If
    Next i

    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I am testing it on https://www.wavemotion.gr/el/shop/wireless-audio/go2-portable-bluetooth-speaker-ipx7-waterproof-7

Comment: thanks for sharing. I guess you can give my code a go and if problems let me know and I will have a play.

Comment: Now we speak it is on the 4th row of total 28 the link on which is now is https://www.wavemotion.gr/el/shop/smartphone-accessories/itap-magnetic-air-vent-car-mount

Comment: Did you test with the above?

Comment: Yes it is working but now, the highlight of row is very fast and it is not quite obvious if a row is not readable for a reason( large image files) does it go to next row?

Comment: yes it should continue to next url. Try it with two urls to see. You can add a print statement to check the urls being processed.

Comment: Is there a reason that we check for availability is nothing and not the link itself?

Comment: yes.. so you can exit early the loop and later so you only execute the necessary lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to change your check for if the page has loaded. In my code it times how long it has taken to load exits the loop after 10 seconds.

I have added a boolean that changes to false if more than 10 seconds has passed. This is later used in the if statement to check if the rest of the code should be run.

```
t = Timer
booLoaded = true

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState < 4

  DoEvents

  If Timer - t > 10 Then
    booLoaded = false
    Exit Do
    t = ""
  end if

loop

t = timer

if booload = true then
   Do
   DoEvents
'... rest of the do loop here
end if

next i
```